# Trying to `viewDidLoad-Embed` a UINavigationController subclass in a Container View using AutoLayout

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, uicontainerview, ios-autolayout

**TARGET**:

To achieve [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3y0K.png).

**APPROACH**:

- Read about **Container Views**
- Found [`RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers`](https://github.com/cwRichardKim/RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers#demo)
- Thought of *blending both in to one*

**GLITCH**:

The aforementioned *Third Party* (`RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers`) is basically a child of `UINavigationController`, manipulating `UIPageViewController` and `UIScrollView`, and so, what I am trying to achieve here... is to have this *NavController* **embedded** in to the `Container View`.

**OUTCOME**:

This, however, doesn't work and shows a black container where I'm **`viewDidLoad-embedding`** the `RWSwipeViewControllers`.

**REFERRED**:

The following, however, of no use to me:

- [Embedding a navigation controller in a container - Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36056812/embedding-a-navigation-controller-in-a-container-objective-c)
- [iOS - NavController & Custom Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988377/ios-navcontroller-custom-views)

Comment: Can anybody at least provide a direction to move forward, if not the solution itself? ...cause otherwise, was thinking of going with the approach of creating a View Controller with Buttons as tabs and a common ScrollView where I'd add Gestures, in addition to changing the content offset of the ScrollView on tap of buttons.

Comment: that does sounds like a good way to go. Look into UIPageViewController for handling swipable view controllers

Comment: Hey, thanks @mattsven! But you mean, without using **Container Views**?

Comment: I've not used Container Views heavily, but UIPageViewController should act similarly, in this case

Comment: Hmmm, will try and get back to you.

Right now, I'm working on using a mix of `UICollectionView` and `UITableView` in a `UIViewController`, as suggested by a friend.

Answer (score 0):

Basically just add the ViewController into a UINavigationController and set the UINavigationController as your rootViewController:

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];

self.window.rootViewController = nvc;
```

or else

If you want to add navigation controller with storyboard then it's very simple, just follow these steps:

- select the storyboard to which you want to attach a storyboard,
- go to toolbar then,
- Editor->Embed In->Navigation controller,
- your storyboard automatically embedded with navigation controller.

Referred this link

[Embedding a navigation controller in a container - Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36056812/embedding-a-navigation-controller-in-a-container-objective-c?lq=1)

Comment: I just wish you had gone through what I had written... :|